# Ethernet speed drop to 10Mbs when connecting to LAN

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have trouble reading video from a camera's encoder address. The address is on my LAN, and I am connected to this network through ethernet.

Everytime I start my computer and plug my ethernet cable afterward, the ethernet speed drop from 1000Mbs to 10Mbs, which compromise the reading of the stream.
dmesg give:

```
enp0s31f6 NIC Link is up 10 Mbs Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx

enp0s31f6 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
```

Setting the speed to 1000Mbs makes it work again.

How can I be sure that the speed is not dropping everytime I connect my computer to my network?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had to update my Kernel to avoid this problem